# Frequency of strings and their IDs in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, frequency, text-mining

The goal is to generate the frequency of a text variable and associate the corresponding IDs with it.

Suppose Sample is a dataframe as shown below:

```
Sample <- data.frame(ID = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'), 
                        Var = c('How are you', 
                                 'Do not go', 
                                 'How are you', 
                                 'Please go',  
                                 'How are you',
                                 'Do not go'))
```

The following command generates the frequency of the strings in the column Var as follows:

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(Sample$Var), ', '))))
```

[image]

Is there a way to generate the associated IDs together in the table, say as?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(with(Sample, split(Sample, Var)), function(x){
      with(x, data.frame(Var = unique(Var), Freq = nrow(x), ID = toString(ID)))
   }
  )
), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the approach without any additional packages

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
New <- Sample %>% group_by(Var) %>%
  summarise(Freq=n(),IDS=toString(ID))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Var          Freq IDS    
  <chr>       <int> <chr>  
1 Do not go       2 2, 6   
2 How are you     3 1, 3, 5
3 Please go       1 4
```

Comment: @Ray Always a pleasure helping you :)

Comment: Good answer! I learnt from your `dplyr` answer since I am still a newbie for that :P +1!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option if you apply `data.table`

```
> setDT(Sample)[, .(Freq = .N, ID.asso = list(ID)), keyby = Var]
           Var Freq ID.asso
1:   Do not go    2     2,6
2: How are you    3   1,3,5
3:   Please go    1       4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the alternate approach using data.table

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` with `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Sample %>%
   group_by(Var) %>%
    summarise(Freq = n(), IDS = str_c(ID, collapse=", "))
```

Comment: Thanks for another approach